# Is there a free diff tool that allows in-line edits - like Beyond Compare?

Tags: diff

I use KDiff3, but miss Beyond Compare's ability to modify text (or undo changes) while looking at the diff output. Is there any free windows tool that allows it?

Comment: To clarify, I am not looking for a (3 way) merge tool; I want to see 2 panels - left and right side, and move line(s) from left to right with one button click, like I can in Beyond Compare. Or - double click on a line on either side and start typing, and then save the file.

Comment: Meld does all these things...

Comment: `diffuse` is one such tool and it offers integration with various VCSs, too.

Answer (score 15):

[Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) is easily the best (free) merge tool I've used.

Comment: The Meld portable version on Windows does not run on my end, it is 5 days old, so I am guessing it is a bit raw at the moment. Looks promising though ...

Comment: I also can't run Meld on Windows 7

Answer (score 4):

I was quite happy with [SourceGear DiffMerge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) before I switched to BeyondCompare. The main thing BC had that made me switch was the current-line diff at the bottom of the screen (which is great for long lines).

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with http://winmerge.org/ but I still thought Beyond Compare was worth the $30.  My employer paid for it happily.

Answer (score -2):

There is such a tool at [www.scmlite.com](http://www.scmlite.com). It is free and has good edition capabilities from inside the side by side windows. It lets you compare files or directories, and also synchronize two directories which is very handy to sync your backup. It is windows only at the moment. sqlite based.

Comment: Link contains suspicious redirection and content.

Comment: Link is dead now.